# Return value from dedicated TryParse Method c#

Tags: c#, tryparse

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere online to my problem.

I'm trying to write a `Int.TryParse` Method in a seperate class, Which can be called upon whenever the user makes an input. So instead of writing this everytime there is an input:

```
    int z;
    int.TryParse(Console.writeLine(), out z);
```

Im trying to make this happen (from main method)

```
int z; 
Console.WriteLine("What alternative?");   
Try.Input(Console.ReadLine(), z); // sends the input to my TryParse method
```

The tryparse Method

```
 class Try
    {

    public static void Input(string s, int parsed)
    {
        bool Converted = int.TryParse(s, out parsed);

        if (Converted)      // Converted = true
        {
            return;                
        }
        else                //converted = false
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0}: Is not a number.\n\nPress ENTER to return", s);
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
    }       

    } 

}
```

Why does my the Variabel "z" get the value of "parsed" when the program return the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to communicate the `parsed` value to the calling method, you will either need to `return` it or make it available as an `out` parameter, like `int.TryParse()` does.

Returning the value is the most straightforward way, but it doesn't provide a way to know whether the parsing succeeded. However, if you change the return type to a `Nullable<int>` (aka `int?`), then you can use a null return value to indicate failure.

```
public static int? Input(string s)
{
    int parsed;
    bool Converted = int.TryParse(s, out parsed);

    if (Converted)      // Converted = true
    {
        return null;                
    }
    else                //converted = false
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\n{0}: Is not a number.\n\nPress ENTER to return", s);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return parsed;
    }
}      


Console.WriteLine("What alternative?");   
int? result = Try.Input(Console.ReadLine()); 
if(result == null)
{
    return;
}
// otherwise, do something with result.Value
```

Using an `out` parameter would mirror the `int.TryParse()` method signature:

```
public static bool Input(string s, out int parsed)
{
    bool Converted = int.TryParse(s, out parsed);

    if (Converted)      // Converted = true
    {
        return false;                
    }
    else                //converted = false
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("\n{0}: Is not a number.\n\nPress ENTER to return", s);
        Console.ReadLine();
        return true;
    }
}       

Console.WriteLine("What alternative?");   
int z;
if(!Try.Input(Console.ReadLine(), out z))
{
    return;
}
// otherwise, do something with z
```